# Oracle database linux flavor

Tags: linux, oracle

Can someone recommend me a linux flavor to install an oracle database on? I have no preferences for any flavor.

Is there  flavor which is easier than others? Or has less issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I believe the only platforms that are officially supported are RHEL, SLES, and OUL. So if you need support from Oracle, you'll need to stick with those distros. If that's not a concern, just pick whatever distro you're most comfortable with.

If I were to recommend one of the supported distros, I'd recommend going with either RHEL or OUL. They're basically identical to each other. For a non-supported distro, I prefer either Debian or CentOS

Answer (score 3):

Linux Distros for the XE version are [here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/xe/files/install.102/b25144/toc.htm#r2c1-t3)

For 11gR2, they can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e10840/pre_install.htm#CHDFFBIF)

If you just want to "Install and Go" on a 64-bit version, then have a look at HJR's [GOAL](http://diznix.com/oracle/goal/) as it will do the grunt work of getting necessary packages etc.

Comment: Well done - I spent a couple minutes trying to locate the above links, but was defeated :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the distros mentioned by @ErikA, you can also use CentOS, which is RHEL-based, minus the RH proprietary extensions. I don't think it's an "officially blessed by Oracle" distro, but I've installed Oracle on it without issue.